# How to start a new activity from a non activity class in Android kotlin?

Tags: java, android, notifications, kotlin

I've been trying to pass the context but it just doesn't work
so I declare it first using

```
var mContext: Context? = null
```

then in one of my function (from non activity class) I call it

```
val intent= Intent(mContext, NotificationActivity::class.java)
mContext?.startActivity(intent)
```

It doesn't show error in coding but when I run this app, it just doesn't work

NotificationActivity is the class that I want to call

Comment: no, my question is different. i'm using kotlin

Comment: you need to pass `Context` in your class that's it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is something like this.

and you can use it Like [Non Activity Example Using Kotlin](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Basic-Kotlin-Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/kotlintutorial/utils/Utils.kt)

```
 Utils.startNewActivity(this,SecondActivity::class.java)


 Utils.startNewActivity(this@MainActivity,SecondActivity::class.java)
```

if you are performing onClick or using adapter then you can get Context from its View like

```
 Utils.startNewActivity(view.context,SecondActivity::class.java)









    class Utils {

        companion object {
            fun startActivity(context: Context, clazz: Class<*>) {

                val intent = Intent(context, clazz)

               // start your next activity

                context.startActivity(intent)

            }
        }

}
```

or

```
object Utils {

     fun startNewActivity(context: Context, clazz: Class<*>) {

            val intent = Intent(context, clazz)
// To pass any data to next activity
//            intent.putExtra("keyIdentifier", value)
// start your next activity
            context.startActivity(intent)

        }


}
```

Non Activity Class with Constructor.!

```
 UtilsWithConstructor(this@MainActivity).startNewActivity(SecondActivity::class.java)

class UtilsWithConstructor(private val context: Context) {

      fun startNewActivity(clazz: Class<*>) {

    val intent = Intent(context, clazz)
    // start your next activity
    context?.startActivity(intent)

}


}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but view.context is still error . it says Unresolved reference : view. I put Utils.startNewActivity inside the function and the object Utils outside my function

Comment: use this@MainActivity or this to get context.!

Comment: So i just change my code to         Utils.startNewActivity(this,NotificationActivity::class.java)
 but it says type missmatch. required: Context

Comment: Utils.startNewActivity(this@MainActivity,NotificationActivity::class.java)

Comment: i've been replacing my code with that but still no luck. the error is still the same. type mismatch. Required: Context. Found: MainActivity

Comment: check your activity name  @MainActivity mean's you are in MainActivity.java

Comment: my non activity's class that i actually want to call another activity named mainLogic. the destination is NotificationActivity and i actually have changed it to Utils.startNewActivity(this@mainLogic, NotificationActivity::class.java)  the error is still the same .

Comment: ok pass context in constructor and then call its method.