# Android Kotlin Starting Activity From Utils Class Results In SavedInstanceState Being Null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

Just to clarify beforehand, I have searched extensively in SO for similar question to find an answer to my question.

I will reference the following (to name a few sources) :

- [How to start a new activity from a non activity class in Android kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745488/how-to-start-a-new-activity-from-a-non-activity-class-in-android-kotlin)
- [Start a new Activity from non Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664463/start-a-new-activity-from-non-activity-class)
- [Basic Kotlin Tutorial](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Basic-Kotlin-Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/kotlintutorial/utils/Utils.kt)

I have a MainActivity and four other different activities, let's call them A through D.

I also have a Utilities class which sets on click listeners to image buttons found in activities A through D.

These listeners then open a new activity, E.

> For some reason, in the `onCreate` method for activity E, `savedInstanceState` is always null.
>   I have tried setting the listener from the MainActivity, but to no avail.
>   I have also passed the context from the MainActivity (instead of using the scroll view's), but that had not effect either

Below is a snippet of the code.

**Utilities.kt**

```
class Utilities {

companion object {
    /...

    fun setTooltipsAndListeners(scrollView: ScrollView) {
        val buttons: ArrayList<View> = scrollView.touchables
        for (button in buttons) {
            val tooltipText = button.contentDescription
            if (tooltipText != null) {
                TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(button, tooltipText)
            }

            button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {

                    val tag: String? = v?.tag as? String
                    val intent = Intent(scrollView.context, ActivityE::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("symbol_name", tooltipText)
                    intent.putExtra("symbol_image", tag)

                    scrollView.context.startActivity(intent)

                }
            })

        }
    }

   /...
}
```

**ActivityE.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)
    setDataToUI(savedInstanceState)
}

private fun setDataToUI(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d("TAG", "savedInstanceState IS NULL")
        return
    }

  /... Inner logic that is not relevant
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `savedInstanceState` you need to use `getIntent()`. So your code will change like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)
    setDataToUI(intent)
}

private fun setDataToUI(intent: Intent?) {

    if (intent.getStringExtra("symbol_name") == null) {
        Log.d("TAG", "No data passed for symbol_name")
        return
    }
    // Do the same for other strings. Or alternatively, you can pass Bundle 
    // data from your Utility and retrieve the bundle through the intent as well
}
```

`savedInstanceState` is used to store data when the state of the activity is changed, but you are passing data through an `Intent` in your utility class